# How to figure out the nearest sum of two sub array in 2N array? Consider to find optimal one

Tags: arrays, algorithm, numbers

Here's my problem.

There's one unsorted array with 2N elements. All these elements are positive integer.
   Q: How to split this array into two N array and the sum of two array must be most close to each other

One intuitive thought is,

1. sort this array to a1< a2 < a3< ...< a2N and
2. split them to two sub array a1 a3 a5 ... a(2N-1) and [a2,a4,...a2N] ,
   then swith two number in each aray, and keep looping util we find the smallest one between the two array.

But in this way, we can't sure that we find the optimal one.

Comment: As stated by PengOne, this problem is NP-complete. To find the exact solution you would have to test all the C(2n,n)=(2n)!/(n!)² combinations ... <br>
Matbe this article could provide some help : [A Complete Anytime Algorithm for Balanced Number Partitioning](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.31.5223), other references like [Performance Ratios for the Differencing Method Applied to the Balanced Number Partitioning Problem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.12.7173) can point you to different algorithms you could implement.<br>

Answer (score 5):

This is the [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), and it's hard (i.e. NP-complete).

That said, if you need to implement this, then the greedy algorithm you suggest does a decent job. You can do a little better by ensuring that one list isn't always less than the other by taking 1 from the first, 2 from the second, 2 from the first, ..., 1 from the second:

```
A = [a1, a4, a5, a8, a9, ..., a(n-2), a(n-1)]
B = [a2, a3, a6, a7, ..., a(n-4), a(n-3), an]
```

This does not always give an optimal solution, but it does well enough for most cases. It also keeps out the bias for "going first".

Comment: For a nice article on this topic, see: [The easiest hard problem](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/2002/3/the-easiest-hard-problem)

Answer (score 2):

You should look up the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). In your case you are shooting for a subset sum of S/2 where S is the the full set sum. There is a simple dynamic programming algorithm to do it in the case of integers, which is the best known.  Unfortunately it's pseudo-polynomial time.  This means that run time is a polynomial in the *size* of the elements.  This makes it exponential time in the normal sense, but it works fine if the elements are not too large.

The subset sum dynamic program needs a little modification to enforce the requirement for  exactly N elements e[i].  Let Q(i, s, n) be true iff there exists a subset consisting of elements selected from 1 to i summing to s and containing exactly n<=i elements.

Then

Q(i, s, n) = Q(i - 1, s, n) or Q(i - 1, s - e[i], n - 1)

The base case says that using no elements at all, the sum and the required number in the subset must both be zero, otherwise Q is false:

Q(0, 0, 0) = true, otherwise Q(0, _, _) is false.

To get the answer, compute the DP table for Q(2N, k, N), k = ceiling(S/2), ceiling(S/2)-1, ... until you find a true value.

Note that this problem is close enough to subset sum to make it NP hard. This means a true polynomial time algorithm (like your sorting proposal) will be an approximation of optimality.  Of course that may well be just fine for realistic purposes.

Comment: It won't work for {1,1,1,3}, subset sum S/2 yields {1,1,1} {3} but the answer should be {1,1} {1,3} I guess

Comment: Ah but there is a trivial modification to the subset sum dynamic program that solves your problem.  I will edit to show you since you're not seeing it.

Comment: The sum subset problem doesn't constrain the sizes of the two sets.

Comment: I'll add that there's a proof that this problem (and subset sum, too) is NP hard.  So solutions involving greediness, sorting, etc. that are truly polynomial time will be approximations. For many applications these are likely to be good enough, for sure.